# Need Help Improving 3 Similar Excel Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 formulas that parse data from a cell looking for 3 specific codes: P, U, and AT. If they find these codes, they should convert them into numerical values. If the cell has just the code without any number preceding it, the formulas should convert the value into 8 (ie: P -> 8, U -> 8 or AT -> 8). If there is a number preceding the code, the formulas should convert the value into that number (ie: 2P -> 2, 5U -> 5 or 1AT -> 1). For the most part, these formulas work great as long as there aren't multiple codes in the same cell. However, the formulas will sometimes produce #VALUE errors if the cell has multiple codes within it. Here are some test cases that produce #VALUE errors, and the -> represents what the formulas should produce instead of #VALUE errors:

```
OT 30; 2P                  -> P formula should produce 2
4P,OT 10                   -> P formula should produce 4
2.75P; OT 15               -> P formula should produce 2.75
P / OT 10                  -> P formula should produce 8
4.75U/OT 30                -> U formula should produce 4.75
P ; OT 60                  -> P formula should produce 8
2.25U, 3AT                 -> U formula should produce 2.25, AT formula should produce 3
0.75U,OT 10                -> U formula should produce 0.75
2AT; 0.25U                 -> AT formula should produce 2, U formula should produce 0.25
0.75U/OT 10                -> U formula should produce 0.75
3.5U/2.5AT                 -> U formula should produce 3.5, AT formula should produce 2.5
U / 2AT                    -> U formula should produce 8, AT formula should produce 2
1.75U / OT 10              etc...
0.08333AT; OT 10
0.46667AT; OT 10
2AT; OT 10
AT/ OT 60
1AT; OT 20
1AT/1P
2AT OT 30
1.25AT; OT 10
3AT; OT 15
1.25AT/3.25U
0.22AT; OT 30
3.5AT; OT 15
2AT/SR
1.5AT/OT 30
```

Can you help me improve or rewrite the 3 formulas listed below to work with the test cases listed above? If the cell has multiple codes, each code will usually be separated from one another with these separators (there may or may not be spaces between the separators and the codes): , / ;

```
P formula: =VALUE(IF(A1="P",8,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("P",A1))),
 0,
 MID(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",A1)),
  IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("P",MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-1))),
   MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-1),
   IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("P",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)),"0")),
  A1),1,LEN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",A1)),
  IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("P",MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-1))),
   MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-1),
   IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("P",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)),"0")),
  A1))-1))))


U formula: =VALUE(IF(A1="U",8,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("U",A1))),
 0,
 MID(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",A1)),
  IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("U",MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-1))),
   MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-1),
   IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("U",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)),"0")),
  A1),1,LEN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",A1)),
  IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("U",MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-1))),
   MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-1),
   IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("U",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)),"0")),
  A1))-1))))


AT formula: =VALUE(IF(A1="AT",8,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("AT",A1))),
 0,
 MID(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",A1)),
  IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("AT",MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-2))),
   MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-2),
   IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("AT",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)),"0")),
  A1),1,LEN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",A1)),
  IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("AT",MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-2))),
   MID(A1, 1,FIND("/",A1)-2),
   IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("AT",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)),"0")),
  A1))-2))))
```

Comment: Would you consider a UDF (VBA)? Or one using a helper column?

Comment: What do you want to extract in case of "2AT; 1P"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, set up header with criteria as in following table.

In `B2` copied across right to `D2` and all copied down :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B$1,$A2)),IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,0+RIGHT(LEFT($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)-1),ROW($1:$99))),8),"")
```

[image]